# Python, The second function does not run when the value of n is greater than 2991

Tags: python-3.x

I have an issue with this code, when i run it with a "n" value greater than 2991, the program does not execute the second function.

```
import time
import sys  

def factorial(n):
    respuesta=1
    while n > 1:
        respuesta *= n
        n-=1
    
    return respuesta

def factorial_r(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial_r(n-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    n = 2991
    print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
    sys.setrecursionlimit(999999)
    print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
    
    comienzo = time.time()
    factorial(n)
    final = time.time()
    print(final - comienzo)


    comienzo2 = time.time()
    factorial_r(n)
    final2 = time.time()
    print('segundo tiempo')
    print(final2 - comienzo2)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: why do you think it's not running?

Answer (score 0):

1. your recursion limit code isn't doing anything
2. your code runs fin for me

```py
import time
import sys  
import math

def factorial(n):
    respuesta=1
    while n > 1:
        respuesta *= n
        n-=1
    
    return respuesta

def factorial_r(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial_r(n-1)

for n in range(2991,3000):
    print(n)
    comienzo = time.time()
    print('fac1',len(str(factorial(n))))
    final = time.time()
    print(final - comienzo)


    comienzo2 = time.time()
    print('fac2',len(str(factorial_r(n))))
    final2 = time.time()
    print('segundo tiempo')
    print(final2 - comienzo2)
    print()
```

results in

```
2991
fac1 9100
0.002978801727294922
fac2 9100
segundo tiempo
0.003741025924682617

2992
fac1 9103
0.003143787384033203
fac2 9103
segundo tiempo
0.004609107971191406

2993
fac1 9107
0.00574493408203125
fac2 9107
segundo tiempo
0.005278825759887695

2994
...
```

etc.